# Как правильно сократить: хим. лаборатория или химлаборатория?

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Как правильно написать сокращенное слово: "хим. лаборатория" (в два слова) или слитно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, оба варианта оформления правильны. Хим. лаборатория - это вариант графического сокращения слова.  Химлаборатория - это одно сложносокращенное слово. Выбор варианта зависит от условий употребления.

В этом случае возникает еще вопрос: а где есть список всех сложносокращенных слов? Возможно, есть специальный словарь. В обычных может не быть. В моем, например, есть химзавод, химлаборатории нет. Но и завотделом нет, а у Лопатина приводится пример двоякого написания. И все-таки, я считаю, есть химзавод, а на нем есть химлаборатория.